# With NewtonSoft, how to create an array of strings with JArray

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got the following code that returns an aggregate exception.  I essentially want to create what will be a simple list of strings.

```
        JArray jArray = new JArray();
        foreach (string id in recipientIds)
        {
            var jsonObject = JObject.FromObject( (String)id);
            jArray.Add(jsonObject);
        }
```

The above works when id is a class with setters and getters but not when id is a string.

Comment: Have you tried `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(recipientIds)`? It will return a string like this `[id1, id2, id3]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JToken.FromObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) will work for primitives and collections as well as classes:

```
var jArray = new JArray(recipientIds.Select(s => JToken.FromObject(s)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `JArray`:

```
var recipientIds = new[] {"something", "another thing"};
var jArray = JArray.FromObject(recipientIds);
```