# .NET assign JToken value int array

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I'm  creating a JToken and assign int[] as its value.

I tried passing "[1,2,3,4]" as its value but the server converts it to null.

So is there a way to assign [1,2,3,4] as JToken's value?

Comment: You can use [`JToken.FromObject(new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4}))`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_FromObject.htm) to serialize your integer array as shown e.g. in [Could not determine JSON object type for type “Class”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40722227/3744182) or [With NewtonSoft, how to create an array of strings with JArray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35465163/3744182).

Comment: An even closer duplicate: [Convert an array of string into JArray](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36370638/3744182).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
JToken t = JToken.Parse("[1,2,3,4]");
```

[Documentation link](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonAny.htm)